# Where do I start when trying to create an iOS application with the ability to store data/edit/remove data from a remote server?

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm pretty familiar with xCode in the sense of utilizing a lot of the UI Elements as well as being able to parse XML into tableviews etc. But I want to take it a step further and be able to store data and edit data based on what's posted by the user only etc. I'd be using the Facebook framework for the login, but kind of stumped on what to do from here as far as what I would need to do/ research for being able to store data to a server and having the users edit what they submit to the data. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is too much in your question. There could be **many** starting points. As it is this question is too broad, please narrow it down to a specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to create a rest web service which would handle receiving data from the users and then passing that to a DB server somewhere for storage.  Calling that service from iOS is fairly easy.

Comment: Rest is definitely the latest standard and good practices but any web service (SOAP, Socket connection) would do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best place to start:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service